# How to get sequence number for each value set over a column

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

```
Account Number  Balance SequenceNo
12345           100,00  1
12345           120,52  2
12345           90,02   3
54646           100,56  1
51224           98      1
51224           52      2
```

I have a table , has two columns; account number and balance. How can I generate SequenceNo over Account number ? Each account has it sequence numbers. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this simply by using [row_number() over()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#i86310) analytic function:

```
SQL> with t1(Account_Number, Balance) as(
  2    select 12345, 100.00 from dual union all
  3    select 12345, 120.52 from dual union all
  4    select 12345, 90.02  from dual union all
  5    select 54646, 100.56 from dual union all
  6    select 51224, 98     from dual union all
  7    select 51224, 52     from dual
  8  )
  9  select Account_Number
 10       , balance
 11       , row_number() over(partition by account_number
 12                               order by account_number) as sequence_no
 13    from t1
 14  ;
```

Result:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER    BALANCE SEQUENCE_NO
-------------- ---------- -----------
         12345        100           1
         12345     120.52           2
         12345      90.02           3
         51224         98           1
         51224         52           2
         54646     100.56           1

6 rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the row_number() analytic function.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1438a/2).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your table is `MyTable`, here is how you can achieve that:

```
WITH t1 
     AS (SELECT account_number, 
                balance, 
                rownum R_Num 
         FROM   mytable 
         ORDER  BY account_number), 
     t2 
     AS (SELECT account_number, 
                Min(r_num) Min_R_Num 
         FROM   t1 
         GROUP  BY account_number) 
SELECT t1.account_number, 
       t1.balance, 
       t1.r_num - t2.min_r_num + 1 RecordNo 
FROM   t1, 
       t2 
WHERE  t1.account_number = t2.account_number
```